# TV - Service or Software that notifies you when a tv show season ends or last episode of the season

Tags: web-services, cloud-service

Does anyone know of a software or services that notifies you when a tv show season ends?

- i'd like to only watch them when the season ends instead of every time an episode (new or rerun airs)

There are ones that show when show airs but not interested in that.

Comment: I think that `tv show favs`, its an adroid app, has a custom notification feature, but can't say for sure how it works, its only available in the paid version.

Comment: thanks for the response.  But it would be helpful it there was a service... any way to confirm this? don't have android.